# How to check a `missing return type on function` if my function returns another function?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that returns another function. 
I am using a default config for a CRA with typescript and eslint
`@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type` this rule of eslint tells me I need to describe what is going to be a result of the execution of the first function. It looks like middleware. 
I don't know how to describe a type for that

```js
const fn = a => b => b(a)
```

Comment: "*It looks like middleware*" this is a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) [functional composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)). You just create a new function out of two. Not sure on the exact TS notation for this but `fn` takes a function and returns a function. That resulting function takes a function and returns the result of the second function called with the first as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am talking about carrying. Any idea of how to describe types for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to type it:

```
type Fn = <A>(a: A) => (<B extends (a: A) => any>(b: B) => ReturnType<B>);
let fn: Fn = a => b => b(a);

const str = fn(1)(a => String(a)); // str is string
const num = fn('a')(a => Number(a)) // num is number
const num2 = fn(2)(a => a + 2) // num2 is number
```

[playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAPAQQHwAoCGAuKNASiQyixQCEoIAPYCOAEwGdz9CTEyc4RsARgUpcyAJQjAArgCc4AFXAQqGIgG4AUABtJUAGZwC8JFBykoA8wNzqNGgMYB7OC2BRXMkwawBGIrnMAZWAZAEs4AHMbdSgAelj3EKhQtg9wiIdnVyg4KQBbLzgsAHIcYv8zbigAOXyBCBlouITcgpScuobMlzdWgCZCrD6K8zMAaihh5o68gfbW+pkNIA)

Comment: Where can I read about `<A>` stuff? I am new to TS and I don't follow what this notation means

Comment: <A> stuff is known as "generics".

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html